# Need help sorting multi array

Tags: php, sorting

I see a lot of examples here, but it's not working for me.

I have a list of sorted events retrieved from my DB:

`16.08.2010 12:00:00` - `21.08.2010 20:00:00`
`16.08.2010 20:00:00` - `21.08.2010 23:00:00`
`18.08.2010 17:00:00` - `18.08.2010 19:00:00`

As you can see, the first event is from 16.08 to 21.08.
I need to "chop this up" so that I get one entry foreach day.

This is my function:

```
  function fullList( $data ) {
    $ev = $data['events']; 
    $events = array();

    // Loop through each event. If event spans over several days, add each day in to new event list  
    foreach($ev as $e) :
      $endDate = strtotime(date('Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime($e->endTime)));
      $current = strtotime($e->startTime);

      // Copy event so data is not overwritten
      $newEv = $e;

      while ($current <= $endDate) {

          //Set start date of event to new date
          $newEv->startTime = date('d.m.Y H:i:s', $current);

          // Add events to new event list
          array_push($events,$newEv);

          //Go to next date
          $current = strtotime('+1 day', $current);
      }      
    endforeach;
    // Need to sort $events here
  }
```

Now `$events` contains all events, but it's not sorted by date. I've tried [uasort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php), but I can't use `uasort($array, 'cmp');`.

How can I go about sorting this array by date?

Comment: It would be more efficient to do it via MySQL ORDER BY parameter.

Comment: Why can't you use uasort (or usort which would be more appropriate)?

Comment: FYI, you aren't copying `$e` by assigning it to `$newEnv`, you just creating another reference. To copy an object, use [clone](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php)

Comment: @Nazariy  - initial list is retrieved from DB ordered by s.time. Thanks @Phil Brown - I forgot that.

Comment: You can use few columns in ORDER statement and group them if necessary, like: ORDER BY event_date DESC, event_time ASC

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [natural sorting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

As Nazariy mentioned, you would be better off pre-sorting the events at the source (assuming they come from a DB).

If you must sort the array in code, you should be able to use usort. I'm assuming you want to sort by `startTime`

```
usort($events, function($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a->startTime) - strtotime($b->startTime);
});
```

Comment: I've added some extra info in my Q. The initial event list is retrieved in order from DB. Thanks for the tip on `usort.` I'll test this.